# Solving a non exact differential equation given the form of its integrating factor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am tasked with solving the differential equation 
$$
(3y-2xy^3)dx+(4x-3x^2y^2)dy=0
$$
given that it has an integrating factor of the form $x^py^q=I(x,y)$.

My work: Given that $x^py^q=I(x,y)$, we have for some integer $p,q$ the relation
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}[4x^{p+1}-3x^{p+2}y^{q+2}]=
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}[3y^{q+1}-2x^{p+1}y^{q+3}]\\
\Rightarrow 4(p+1)x^p-3(p+2)x^{p+1}y^{q+2}=3(q+1)y^q-2(q+3)x^{p+1}y^{q+2}
$$
Which I think leads to an inconsistent system, since I need $p=-1$ and $q=-1$ in order to zero the unmatched terms but also $3p+6=2q+6\Rightarrow 3p=2q$. Where am I going wrong? I probably should not assume that I need to zero the $x^p$ and $y^q$ terms, but why?

Comment: **Hint:** What if you write it as $(3 y) dx + (4 x) dy +(-2xy^3) dx + (-3 x^2y^2)dy = 0$? The first two terms lead to an I.F. of $I(x, y) = x^{a-1} y^{b-1} = x^2 y^3$. Multiply the original equation by that I.F. and see if you have an exact equation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want an exact equation of the form $M dx + N dy$, and since it is not exact, we multiply it by the I.F., $I(x, y) = x^p y^q$ and want to solve for $p$ and $q$ to make it exact, so have:

$$x^p y^q ((3y-2xy^3)dx+(4x-3x^2y^2)dy=0)$$

When we differentiate, we have:

$$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 3(q+1)x^py^q - 2 (q+3) x^{p+1}y^{q+2} $$

$$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} = 4(p+1) x^p y^q - 3(p+2)x^{p+1}y^{q+2}$$

Notice that this was not written correctly in your answer (although it looks like you did it correctly).

We equate like terms to get $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, and get:

$$3 (q + 1) = 4(p+1)\\-2(q+3) = -3 (p+2)$$

This leads to the simultaneous equations:

$$3q - 4 p = 1\\-2q +3p = 0$$

This leads to:

$$p=2, ~ q = 3$$

So, the integrating factor is:

$$I(x, y) = x^2 y^3$$

Notice from my comment that you can avoid all of this error prone math.

Comment: oy I feel silly. And it looks like I should try and avoid that! Thanks

Comment: Been trying to reach you! See: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-criticism-and-constructive-praise